# Change position of store switcher

Tags: layout, switcher

I want to add the store switcher to page/template/links.phtml

And I have this on local.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="languagesreference" as="languagesreference" translate="label">
                <label>Languages reference</label>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="languagesreference">
            <block type="core/template" name="languagesreferenceblock" template="page/switch/languages.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

And on page/template/links.phtml:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('languagesreference') ?>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

UPDATE: I managed to fix it by adding this to local.xml:

```
<reference name="top.links">
    <block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

But I have a lot of uncertainty here.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is firstly remove the current placing of the block with a call to `unsetChild` and then use a call to `insert` to set the new place.

```
<default>
    <reference name="header">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>store_language</name></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="insert"><block>store_language</block></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

This should then allow you to move the position of the language chooser from the standard block to the new block.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('languagesreferenceblock') ?>
```

If it doesnot work check if you have declared it in page.xml:

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="languagesreference" as="languagesreference"/>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I think it is a logical problem.

Comment: Have you cleared cache after making this change?

Comment: I have update check your page .xml

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. I have updated my question with a possible solution, but don't think it's the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Locate `page.xml` file located in `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout` directory.

Find the following code.

```
<block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
```

The above code is placed in `page/html_footer` block, we have to change it's location and insert it in `page/html_header` block as shown below.

```
<block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
```

You can now access the store switcher from the header. Now find the `header.phtml` file located in the `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html`directory.

Add the following PHP code to call the store switcher.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_switcher') ?>
```